# Godot animations don't working properly in multiplayer

Tags: animation, networking, multiplayer, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to learn the online multiplayer in Godot, it was everything going okay until I try to put animations. I don't know what's happening, I'm using the same code for animations that I found in all multiplayer projects but just don't work.

Here's my code:

```
func _process(_delta):
    var horizontal = - int(Input.is_action_pressed("left")) + int(Input.is_action_pressed("right"))
    var vertical = - int(Input.is_action_pressed("up")) + int(Input.is_action_pressed("down"))
    velocity = Vector2(horizontal, vertical).normalized() * speed
    if velocity != Vector2():
        if is_network_master():
            motion = move_and_slide(velocity)
        rpc_unreliable("_set_position", global_position)

# ANIMATIONS ------------------------
    if velocity.length() > 0:
        newAnim = "Run"
    else:
        newAnim = "Idle"
    
    if currentAnim != newAnim:
        currentAnim = newAnim
        animPlayer.play(currentAnim)
```

[Here's the animation in game:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7td.jpg)

The animations are playing in both players, I've tried to put the animation states inside the "if is_network_master" and don't work, I've also tried to use an script on a node attached to the player and use the "get_parent()" but does the same thing.

I have also another question that if anyone could answer, it would be cool

- If I want to have a local multiplayer (same pc) and an online multiplayer, should I have two types of script for player?

Comment: The animations are dependent on velocity. Is velocity changing for the other peers? Maybe track move state and send that to the other peers as well.